# Draggable progressbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a draggable bar much like a progress bar. On page load the bar will be at a percentage predetermined, say 42%, is there a way to make that bar draggable as well? Here is the html:

```
 <div class="reviewAttn_bar"><span id="resizable" style="width:42%"></span></div>
```

The jquery I'm using is:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable({ handles: 'e' });
});
```

Nothing is happening though. The CSS handles the sizing of the span. I'm thinking about creating an arrow graphic up top that the user can use to drag the bar to a different percentage but I can't get this part to work. Any suggestions?

Here is the css I'm using:

```
.reviewAttn_bar {
background-color: #1a1a1a;
-webkit-background-size: 100px 100px;
-moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
background-size: 100px 100px;         
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                    color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                    color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)),
                    color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                    to(transparent));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);            
height: 65px;
width: 280px;
margin: 50px 0 50px -55px;         
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;
```

}

```
.reviewAttn_bar span {
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-background-size: 100px 100px;
-moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
background-size: 100px 100px;         
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                    color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                    color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)),
                    color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                    to(transparent));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                    transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                    transparent 75%, transparent);
height: 71%;   
-moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
```

}

```
#resizable {
display:block;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
[updated the fiddle here with all of your source the handle EAST is also operating just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/tNLek/4/)

note that I am including jquery, jquery ui, AND the jquery-ui CSS file.

[i checked the jquery .resizable() API documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) and

not to beat a dead horse but i noticed adding the handle E removed the bottom right draggable "texture" entirely, while it still works - you have to very specifically mouseover only the right side of the status bar span in order to see the cursor change and know it is resizable.  just wanted to cover all my bases - while you might not "SEE" a difference it is in fact working on the fiddle

---

by default in css all [span elements are "inline" elements](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) - meaning their css display property defaults to

```
display:inline;
```

for the jquery UI .resizable() handler to work properly it must be called on a "block" element such as a div.

[ive taken your code and modified in a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tNLek/3/) the working source is as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="reviewAttn_bar"><span id="resizable" style="width:42%"></span></div>
```

CSS

```
#resizable{
    display:block;        
    border:1px solid red; // can be ignored just to help visualize
    height:30px;          // can be ignored just to help visualize
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
```

removing the {handles: 'e'} parameters from the resizable handler and adding css block style to your #resizable element and everything is now working as expected.

Comment: I added display:block to my code and it didn't work...with or without the handles.

Comment: thanks for additional source, taking a look through your update now

Comment: Give me a few minutes to put the files somewhere you can access it.

Comment: ROTFLOL. I was missing an "s" in the extension. (.cs instead of .css so it couldn't see the custom css file) Thank you for all of your help Joe. I appreciate it.

Comment: happy to help - just couldn't go to bed until i figured this one out! going to add a link to the resizeable api documentation before i do!