# How to track the percentage of the bar while resizing in real time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a progress bar that acts more like a bar chart. I pull the initial width using JSON and have it to where the bar is resizable to the right. [previous work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705115/draggable-progressbar) I'm trying to track and display the changing percentages as the bar is dragged either left or right. My attempts so far have not been fruitful using jquery ui. Does anyone have an example or suggestion I could use to figure this out?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried so far or how you are currently doing it

Comment: I'm not doing it yet. Looking for a place to start using the previous example. I want to track the change in percentage based on the user dragging the bar. Since I used "resizable" in jquery ui and not "progressbar" I'm at a loss how to go about it.

Comment: So you have a resizeable (horizontally) bar, that when resized, you want to calculate the percentage in relation to the original size, correct?

Comment: Yes. (sorry I'm being such a noob)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I was helping you with the correct thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/z9E5U/2/**

I'm gonna show you a vanilla jQuery way of doing it (no jQuery UI). First up, we create our html elements:

```
<div class="dragwrapper" style="margin: auto; width: 100px">
    <div style="width: 120px; height: 20px; background-color:#F00; cursor: w-resize" class="dragme"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">0%</div>
```

So we have a wrapper with a class `.dragwrapper`. This is used to be the reference to which the mouse is moving. Then we have our actual draggable element with a class `.dragme` and a few css attributes to make it visible. I am using an initial size of 120px in this example, but the percentage can easily be calculated regardless of the initial size

For out javascript (make sure you have jQuery loaded):

```
$(function(){
    var initialWidth = 120;
    var dragging = false;

    $('.dragme').mousedown(function(e){
        dragging = true;
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
        e.preventDefault();

        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            if (dragging == true){
                $('.dragme').css("width",e.pageX - parentOffset.left);
                var percentageChange = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) / initialWidth * 100
                $('.result').html(percentageChange + "%");
            }       
        });
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        if (dragging){
            dragging = false;
            console.log('drag stopped');
        }
    });
});
```

So, we are first declaring a variable called `dragging` which is initially set to `false`, as well as a variable holding our initial width. We then listen for a `mousedown` event on the `.dragme` element. We set `dragging` to `true`, get the offset of the wrapper and do a `preventDefault` for good measure. We then follow the mouse movement and change the css of the `.dragme` element

We also listen for a `mouseup` event to stop the dragging if `dragging` variable is `true`

You compare the offset (`e.pageX - parentOffset.left`) with the initial width to calculate the percentage

Hope that helps

Comment: Generally I think jQueryUI is overkill for most things!

Comment: @Amidude rad :) let me know if you need any more help with it

Comment: I'm running into two problems. The number value returned comes back with a decimal point a few digits afterwords. Also, there are multiple bars on the page and they all drag at the same time. I'm working the decimal point issue. The other I'll get too later.

Comment: For the rounding off, use `toFixed()`, like so: `$('.result').html(percentageChange.toFixed(2) + "%");` (where 2 is the number of decimal places). For the multiple bars moving at once, I'll make a jsfiddle to show you how to fix that a little later

Comment: I've got it to where only current bar is resized. Now I'm having an issue with the inner span not stopping at the end of the parent div. I have containment set to parent but it's not working. I also added maxWidth and made that parent as well but it doesn't like it.